# Знаки препинания при вводном слове

Tags: вводные-слова, союзы, тире, запятые

"А то непонятно, ты коммуникабельный(,) значит ( ) легко и эффективно общаешься с клиентами, или ты коммуникабельный(,) значит ( ) любишь трепаться на рабочем месте"

Правильно ли, что перед "значит" поставлены запятые, а не тире? "Значит" здесь союз с оттенком вводного слова.
А после "значит" запятая не ставится, т.к. есть правило, что после вводного слова запятая не ставится, если оно стоит на границе частей сложного предложения и относится к следующему за ним предложению. Верно?
Но почему-то в этой статье (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_220&layout=item) во втором пункте запятые всё же проставлены после слова "значит", хотя оно стоит на границе частей сложного предложения и относится к следующему за ним предложению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**А то непонятно, ты коммуникабельный –  значит,  легко и эффективно общаешься с клиентами, или ты коммуникабельный – значит, любишь трепаться на рабочем месте.**

1) **Здесь оформление такое, как в следующем предложении**: БСП: Послал он мне крест – значит, меня он любит. Сравнить: СПП: Раз вы читаете это мое письмецо, значит, я вас уже покинул.

В СПП используется  двойной союз РАЗ....ЗНАЧИТ, ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ, а в БСП первая часть союза  пропущена. Вводное слово входит в двойной союз, но при этом оформляется как вводное слово, то есть после него ставится запятая. Также и в БСП (при пропущенном союзе).

2) Первая часть "**А то непонятн**о" обособлена запятой, можно считать, что это вводное предложение. Но здесь можно использовать и двоеточие, имеющее изъяснительное значение

3) **Запятая перед ИЛИ ставится**, между группами предложений делается пауза.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ)
Вы написали, что оформляется как вводное слово. А как же правило, что после вводного слова запятая не ставится, если оно стоит на границе частей сложного предложения и относится к следующему за ним предложению? Или оно тут не действует? И еще — в данном предложении, мне кажется, не подразумевается пропущенная часть двойного союза "раз/если".

Comment: 1) У Лопатина нет запятой : http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127 Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня.   Но это спорный вопрос, раньше в текстах запятая писалась. Послышался резкий стук, должно быть, сорвалась ставня. http://poesias.ru/proza/chehov-anton-pavlovich/chehov10321.shtml  В самых современных справочниках вводное слово тоже обособляется в функции союза или части союза.

Comment: 2) Двойной союз используется в СПП, между предложениями ставится запятая. При  отсутствии первой части это БСП, ставится тире, а  вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ (в грамматике) называют дополнительным структурным элементом.  И это более правильно, ведь тире ставится в бессоюзном  предложении. Это как раз ваш случай.

Comment: Согласен. Кстати, Лопатин аргументирует тем, что "вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения". А так как у нас тире, то запятая после вводного слова тем более допустима.

Comment: Да, Вы правы.  В Правилах 1956 года  вводное слово без запятой разрешалось использовать только в уточняющих обособленных оборота (многие поэты, например Жуковский...). В других конструкциях необособленные вводные слова смотрятся иногда совершенно нелепо (порой  их можно спутать со сказуемым), то есть это не лучший способ разделять предложения. И стоит помнить о том, что необособленное вводное слово таковым уже не является, а получают другую функцию. И вот с функцией самостоятельного необособленного союза вводные слова   плохо справляются.